# Dynamic routing in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have 3 different model/controllers. I tried to make something like

```
// routes.rb
get ':type' => ':type#show'
```

but as expected, it did not work. I want to route to a controller according to the type specified in URL. How to achieve that?

Comment: What is `type`? how are you setting it?

Comment: @Pavan It is a row in User class which these 3 classes inherit from.

Comment: @BurakÖzmen try to explain your question briefly

Comment: What values did the `type` have?

Comment: Type is a string and may have 3 different values, lets say A, B and C. And each model/type has its own controller such as AsController, BsController, CsController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a generic controller and use redirect_to there to read `params[:type]` and redirect accordingly, but I don't see why you could not just use proper routes in the first place, eg.

```
get '/some_path/:id', to: 'mycontroller#method'
```

if they are standard CRUD controllers, you'd want to consider using resource type routing.

Comment: I could do that but I did not want to route all three possible types to each control action, which would triple my work. Also I'm new to Rails and trying to extend my knowledge about possible solutions.

Comment: Ok, it'd help if we'd knew names/intentions of those three actions. If they are crud operations, I'd really recommend using resourceful routes, eg.
`resource :thing` would automatically route any `show`, `index`, `create`, `update` etc. requests for controller `ThingsController`. Using those is idiomatic in Rails; if you insist on using custom routes, having 3 lines like in the answer is not that repetitive, and is good for grepping code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to use rails Optional Segment Keys. Rails 3 introduced this syntax for defining optional parts of the URL pattern. Try something like:

```
match ':controller(/:show(/:id))', via: 'get'
```

Put this route last in your routes file since it will act as a catch-all for almost all routes in your app. that don't get matched before hitting this one.  You can make it more specific by specifying a certain action the three different controllers may share etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***constraints***.

```
#routes.rb
get "/type" => "controller_A#show", 
  :constraints => lambda { |request| request.params[:type] == "A" }

get "/type" => "controller_B#show", 
  :constraints => lambda { |request| request.params[:type] == "B" }

get "/type" => "controller_C#show", 
  :constraints => lambda { |request| request.params[:type] == "C" }
```